# What's the difference between a constant, and regular immutable variable, and a static variable?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust, and so far, there appears to be 3 ways to declare variables:

```
const A: u8 = 42;
static A: u8 = 42;
let A: u8 = 42;
```

I get that you can't have a mutable `const`, and the compiler will warn you if it's not all uppercase, and that when you use a `const`, the equivalent of the C pre-compiler will replace every place that `A` appears with a literal `42` (it won't have a consistent memory address).

From a practical standpoint, I don't see a difference between any of these in their immutable form. None of them can be mutated. They can all be used exactly the same. What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

- `const` defines values, which are replaced in the according code
- `static` defines global variables representing memory addresses, ie read-only memory, global atomic counters or locks (+initialization), C-abi interaction, etc
- `let` defines scoped variable bindings

You can not use `let` as global variable (static lifetime), so `static` fits that role. Note, that it also exists as [lifetime annotation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html).

[Reference explanation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0246-const-vs-static.html)

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference?

The question can be easily reduced to `const` vs. immutable `static` because that is the only case that is pretty similar (`let` is intended to introduce variables to the current scope).

`const` is supposed to be used when you don't mind the value to be inlined all over the place. Typically, that means small objects; commonly constant integers. Immutable `static` is used otherwise.

In practice, for most use cases (specially for private items), when considering optimizations done by LLVM, there is usually little difference.

You might need to take a closer look if codegen was particularly bad, if you want to export an object and related low-level concerns.